# A constant number plus an auto-incremented number as primary key in Django ORM?

Tags: django-models, django-orm

In my model I need to be able to create a primary key composed of two different parts. One part is a constant number such as `100`. There should be a second part which I would like Django to auto-increment.

The value should be something like `1001, 1002, 1003, ...` or `100-1, 100-2, 100-3, ...`. Is there anyway to do this in Django ORM? I've looked into Casting but can't figure out anything useful. Maybe I can use a float number like `100.0, 100.1, 100.2`? Would this be a better way?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this a while ago but now I just noticed my question here.

For anyone who might encounter something similar, you can override the `.save` method of the model. It would be better to check if `_state.adding` is `True` before doing it.

`_state.adding` is True while the model has not been saved to the database yet.

I also changed my model's id field from `AutoField` to `CharField`.